# Java Android instantiation of many objects

Tags: java, android, object, garbage-collection

I've a problem with my Android application. My problem is that I have a `List` and I pull on it 40K line of the BDD. When I put all data in my `List` the application becomes slow. Is there a method for optimizing the instantiation of object?

```
private List<ContentValues> addObjects(ResultSet rst) throws DaoException, SQLException {
    //Ajout dans la BDD local SQLlite
    List<ContentValues> values = new ArrayList<>();
    ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
    while (rst.next()) {
        value.put("Numero", rst.getInt("Numéro"));
        value.put("AR_Ref", rst.getString("AR_Ref"));
        value.put.....
        .........;
        values.add(new ContentValues(value));  
    }
    return values;
}
```

Logcat: The GC works a lot.

```
D/dalvikvm&#65109; GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1230K, 5% free 62021K/64839K, paused 377ms
D/dalvikvm&#65109; GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1223K, 5% free 62033K/64839K, paused 367ms
D/dalvikvm&#65109; GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1222K, 5% free 62044K/64839K, paused 401ms
D/dalvikvm&#65109; GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1220K, 5% free 62056K/64839K, paused 412ms
D/dalvikvm&#65109; GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1220K, 5% free 62067K/64839K, paused 418ms
D/dalvikvm&#65109; GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1285K, 5% free 62080K/64903K, paused 420ms
D/dalvikvm&#65109; GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1293K, 5% free 62092K/64903K, paused 428ms
D/dalvikvm&#65109; GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1283K, 5% free 62104K/64903K, paused 420ms
```

Comment: have you considered using lazy loading or pagination?

Comment: if I understood what you say, i use AsyncTask for Load my data and put it on my List<ContentValues>

Comment: Why do you load 40k points ? To display them ?

Comment: @Quentin, no I was thinking more about loading only that portion of data that you need without loading everything else - 40k objects is kind of big number for a mobile device - are you sure that you need to handle such big amount of data at once?

Comment: I load 40K entries from my BDD MS SQL to store the table in Loca with SQLLite.

Comment: You can reuse just one `ContentValues` object if you perform the `insert()` operation immediately. Make sure to do it from inside a transaction though.

Comment: @corsair992 I tried and it's even longer, my problem is with the garbage collector because i do new in my loop. The GC consume time on my application. Actually my smartphone do this action in 3 minutes (Load and Insert in my BDD SQLLite).

Comment: @Quentin: What do you mean "it's even longer"? My suggestion is to _not_ do a "`new`" operation in the loop...

Comment: @corsair992 I've re tried your solution execution take 1minute but the database is empty when i use  mDb.insert("MyTable", null, value);

Comment: @Quentin: Please post your code then.

Comment: @corsair992 Your solution is a best answer, it's work and the database is not empty, I made ​​a mistake when I changed for your solution, i've droped the table after all insert. Now it's work in 50sec and consumes little ram and cpu.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `value` increases more and more every time loop goes.

I think the `value` should be instantiated (inside of and) at the start of the loop and `values` should be added the `value` at the end of the loop.

```
private List<ContentValues> addObjects(ResultSet rst) throws DaoException, SQLException {
    List<ContentValues> values = new ArrayList<>();

    while (rst.next()) {
        ContentValues value = new ContentValues();

        value.put("Numero", rst.getInt("Numéro"));
        value.put("AR_Ref", rst.getString("AR_Ref"));
        value.put.....
        .........;

        values.add(value);  
    }

    return values;
}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution the execution take 3minutes and with my method take 2min11sec.

Comment: @Quentin Ah, I mistook `ContentValues` is a kind of `List`, but it's not. I will delete my answer after a while.